# Draw random numbers from distribution within a certain range

Tags: r, random, distribution

I want to draw a number of random variables from a series of distributions. However, the values returned have to be no higher than a certain threshold.
Let’s say I want to use the gamma distribution and the threshold is 10 and I need n=100 random numbers. I now want 100 random number between 0 and 10. (Say scale and shape are 1.)

Getting 100 random variables is obviously easy...

```
rgamma(100, shape = 1, rate = 1)
```

But how can I accomplish that these values range from 0 to 100?

**EDIT**
To make my question clearer. The 100 values drawn should be *scaled* beween 0 and 10. So that the highest drawn value is 10 and the lowest 0. Sorry if this was not clear...

**EDIT No2**
To add some context to the random numbers I need: I want to draw "system repair times" that follow certain distributions. However, within the system simulation there is a binomial probability of repairs beeing "simple" (i.e. short repair time) and "complicated" (i.e. long repair time). I now need a function that provides "short repair times" and one that provides "long repair times". The threshold would be the differentiation between short and long repair times. Again, I hope this makes my question a little clearer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling

Comment: @Severin's approach has successfully created a random gamma distribution within the parameters "between 0 and 100". If it isn't correct in your opinion, you have not explained the problem accurately.

Comment: I have added the some explanation to the question, in the hope of making it clearer.

Comment: Scaling a the observed min and max of sample from a distribution to a pre-specified min and max is almost certainly the wrong thing to do in any context where you might be using a probability distribution. Maybe you should elaborate on what you trying to do with these random numbers and why you need them to have a pre-specified min and max, despite being random.

Comment: What if simple repairs are not always short and complicated repairs not always long, but rather simple repairs tend to be short and complicated repairs tend to be long? Therefore, for a simple repair, you draw a repair time from a distribution with most probability mass between 0 and 10 and if the repair is complex you can draw its repair type from the distribution of "complex repairs length" which has probability mass elsewhere. I assume you are generating some fake data for whatever reason so you you can choose the model you want.

Comment: Not sure I get the context right - you're trying to model some failures. Do you know that there are two modes of failure? If so, you can make a layered model - first draw the failure mode, then draw repair time from one of two appropriate distributions. Or is it the other way around - you've got only the repair times (that you want to simulate), and you want to distinguish, if the repair was long or short?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with a gamma distribution.
The support of a distribution determine the range of sample data drawn from it.
As the support of the gamma distribution is `(0,inf)` this is not possible.(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

If you really want to have a gamma distribution take a rejection sampling approach as Alex Reynolds suggests.

Otherwise look for a distribution with a bounded/finite support (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions)
e.g. uniform or binomial

Comment: Ok. ;)
Can I somehow define that values in a certain range are drawn with a higher probalbility?

Answer (score 1):

Well, fill vector with rejection, untested code

```
v <- rep(-1.0, 100)
k <- 1
while (TRUE) {
    q <- rgamma(1, shape=1, rate=1)
    if (q > 0.0 && q < 100) {
        v[k] <- q
        k<-k+1
        if (k>100)
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: Also using `while(TRUE)` is a waste of condition. The condition is there to set up a break point in the flow. Try `while(k <= 100)` and take out the final two lines.

Comment: @user3347232 `This code returns no numbers higher than 1.5` that might be true, after all you want no number below 100 (or 10?), so conditions are clearly satisfied. If you want something different, please state what exactly do you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can keep the properties of the original distribution, imposing additional conditions... But something like this will do the job:

```
Filter(function(x) x < 10, rgamma(1000,1,1))[1:100]
```

For the scaling - **beware, the outcome will not follow the original distribution** (but there's no way to do it, as the other answers pointed out):

```
# rescale numeric vector into (0, 1) interval
# clip everything outside the range 
rescale <- function(vec, lims=range(vec), clip=c(0, 1)) {
  # find the coeficients of transforming linear equation
  # that maps the lims range to (0, 1)
  slope <- (1 - 0) / (lims[2] - lims[1])
  intercept <- - slope * lims[1]

  xformed <- slope * vec + intercept

  # do the clipping
  xformed[xformed < 0] <- clip[1]
  xformed[xformed > 1] <- clip[2]

  xformed
}

# this is the requested data
10  * rescale(rgamma(100,1,1))
```

Comment: I was not able to draw numbers higher than 2.5

Comment: Ah - rephrase the question then, please, if the problem is not limiting the possible values, but rather scaling up the outcome. Maybe if you provide a broader context of your efforts (why are you doing all this)...

Comment: I have added some context to the question. I hope that makes it a little clearer...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use truncdist package. It truncates any distribution between upper and lower bounds.
Hope that helped.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.